# Prevent Twitter Bootstrap Affix from scrolling beyond point

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, affix

When using [Twitter Bootstrap's Affix feature](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix), I can set the `offset` from the top of the page, so that once the user scrolls *past* the `offset` point, the sidebar will scroll along with the user down the page.

On some pages, once the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, my affix sidebar scrolls beyond the content section of the page into my `sub-footer` and `footer` of the page as shown in the image below.

**QUESTION:** How can I prevent the affixed item from floating lower than my content section (shown here by the last FAQ accordion)?

**UPDATE (added code)**

```
<body data-target="#more-questions" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="125">
  <!-- ... more code ... -->
    <div class="row" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="1">
      <div class="span3" id="more-questions">
        <div class="content-bubble drop-shadow curved">
          <h3 class="uppercase"><i>Do You Still Have <strong>Questions?</strong></i></h3>
          <a href="contact-us.php" class="btn btn-prime">CONTACT US</a> </div>
        <div class="content-bubble-triangle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- ... more code ... -->
</body>
```

[image: Twitter Bootstrap Affix sidebar scrolled below content section]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unpin Twitter bootstrap's affix on scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417818/unpin-twitter-bootstraps-affix-on-scroll)

Answer (score 0):

**update** when the height of the scroll area under your bottom offset is bigger then the affixed element height the calculation goes wrong. After your element is set to the absolute position set by affix-bottom this position is used in the next calculation. So your class will change from affix to affix-bottom again and again when scrolling down.

Try this fix:

```
var tmp = $.fn.affix.Constructor.prototype.checkPosition;
$.fn.affix.Constructor.prototype.checkPosition = function () {
  if(($(document).height()-this.$window.scrollTop())<this.options.offset.bottom && this.$element.hasClass('affix-bottom')) return;
  tmp.call(this);
  }
```

see: http://plnkr.co/voYMKdQP75XnalDeHUTB

<strike>Maybe your css settings are wrong? Look at the menu at:
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html
it got: `<ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix">`</strike>

The affix is set by javascript:

```
// side bar
setTimeout(function () {
  $('.bs-docs-sidenav').affix({
    offset: {
      top: function () { return $window.width() <= 980 ? 290 : 210 }
    , bottom: 270 
    }
  })
}, 100)
```

When you load the page and don't scroll the `affix` class of the `ul` 
is changed to `affix-top`. The list don't have to change position so there 
is no css rule defined for `affix-top`.

When you start scrolling between 290/210px from top and 270px from 
bottom (the `affix-top` will be removed) the `affix` class is applied 
to your list (ul).
`.affix` gets `.affix {
    position: fixed;
}`  from bootstrap.css and 
`.bs-docs-sidenav.affix {
    top: 40px;
}`  from docs.css (you have to define this!)

When you scroll under the 270px from bottom the `affix` class is 
changed to `affix-bottom`. So the `affix-bottom` class is applied 
to your list (ul). 
`.bs-docs-sidenav.affix-bottom {
    bottom: 270px;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
}` from docs.css (you will have to define this too!)

Comment: It appears when I scroll on my page that the `affix-bottom` class never gets applied. What's the reason for this?

Comment: it seems you also have to set the data-offset-bottom for your affix-bottom